# Automatize json objects creation from Array

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, json4s

I am trying to automatize the creation of a `json` object from an `ArrayBuffer[Array[String]]()`, where I have the field and its value saved, to throw it into a database (`mongodb`).

I can't find a way to do that.

I am using `scala` and `json4s`.

Would anyone know a method to answer this?

Comment: Can you not just apply the native data structure into your MongoDB insert/update anyway? The driver should be able to handle it or at least re-cast. I know the play framework has fancy JSON things, but that should not be the "go to" option for working with a data structure you already have. And surely this is more than just an array of strings. If not then what do you expect the resulting document(s) to look like?

Comment: Great idea! I have succeeded in saving the object in the database using `DBObject` rather than creating a `json` object then saving it. Still, I would be interested in knowing how to automatize `json` from dynamic `String`s.

Comment: The general idea is "work native". You should never need to translate to JSON just to speak to MongoDB. Perhaps a misconception as MongoDB speaks "BSON" and not "JSON".

Comment: Good point. I got it wrong, I tried `json`.